# Books to use for NSEA (first stage of IOAA in India)

Tags: resource-request, education

Someone please guide me for [IOAA](https://International%20Olympiad%20on%20Astronomy%20and%20Astrophysics%20%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Olympiad_on_Astronomy_and_Astrophysics) (most likely [NSEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Standard_Examination_in_Astronomy), i.e., the first stage of IOAA in India), like what material and books to use for mathematics, physics and astronomy and is it too late to start my preparation in the 11th class?

Comment: Do you already have text books for maths to CBSE Class 12 and Physics to class 10?  Many of the questions are maths and physics based, rather than specifically astronomical.

Comment: Yes ,I have ncert books but they are not relevant to ioaa as far I know any other recommendation?

Comment: Many of the questions are maths and physics.  So much of [the paper](https://www.iapt.org.in/) can be done without any specifically astronomical knowledge.  You should look at the topics on the [syllabus](https://www.iapt.org.in/images/nse_2022/syllabus-for-nse-ino-2022-2023.pdf) (page 17) It notes that "Any in-depth knowledge of astronomy is not required. However, basic familiarity with astronomical
terminology, objects and phenomena, as can be acquired through an interest in astronomy (reading
popular books / listening to popular lectures etc.), is expected."

Comment: So an astronomical text book is not expected. Any text book suitable for Indian High School students studying maths and physics should be acceptable.

Comment: book recommendations are a bit off topic, and book recommendations for Indian students in maths and physics is more so. Google tells me that the NCERT books are widely used. And as the syllabus for maths and physics is the CBSE content, they should be suitable for NSEA

Comment: @JamesK can you cite a source for "book recommendations are a bit off topic" please? I've added the [tag:resource-request] tag which says "**Questions asking "What is a good book about X?" or more generally, "What should I read to learn about X?"**, typically where there is not a single authoritative reference. Also requests for multimedia, like video lectures."

Comment: recommendations of maths books are not on topic.

Comment: And general requests "a book about astronomy" is too opinion based.  I've linked to the syllabus which says that specific astronomical skills are not required, only general astronomical concepts and terminology.  But you'll note I've not voted to close. It's possible that someone can write a good answer to this.  If someone knows more about textbooks in India than me they can answer.  I'd suggest that the OP start with the syllabus and past papers

Comment: Related: *[Policy on asking for book recommendations](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237/policy-on-asking-for-book-recommendations)*

Comment: Related: *[Reference material](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163/reference-material)* (a resource recommendations list on meta. Though not very developed)

Answer (score 3):

I've bagged a gold medal for India in the IOAA-Jr, so I think I may answer your question to some extent.

Math and Physics are pretty standard introductory JEE level stuff they ask in NSEA. If you take out some standard JEE book, you might as well be done doing just till the medium level exercises. Important concepts like gravitation, magnetism, mechanics should be done at a bit more depth.

They don't ask too much hardcore astronomy in the first stage. Just learn some basic definitions from 'Astronomy: Principles and Practice, A.E. Roy, D.Clarke' like stellar magnitudes, Lagrange points. This book is literally god for astro olympiad aspirants. Look up the chapter on celestial coordinates. Don't delve into the math part of it now, only understand the basic terms, and voila! You're good to go for NSEA! You can look up some constellations and learn spherical trig too if you wanna be on the safer side (but that's more relevant only for INAO). Anyways, love Astronomy and keep working hard. I wish you the best of luck!